# Connect local container docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose configuration file with the following settings:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - devnetwork
  discovery:
    image: discovery
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - devnetwork
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev  
      - DISCOVERY_SERVER=discovery
      - DISCOVERY_PORT=8761

networks:
  devnetwork:
```

After up compose I build and run the following dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:12    
#RUN echo $(grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts | cut -f1) api >> /etc/hosts
ADD gubee-middleware/target/*.jar /usr/share/middlewareservice/middleware-service.jar
EXPOSE 9670
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions","-XX:+UseContainerSupport","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "-jar", "/usr/share/middlewareservice/middleware-service.jar"]
```

How do I make my port 9670 service dockerfile see other services that I start with docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the container to the network created by docker compose when you start it.

This can be done by passing `--network=<network-name>` (obtain by running `docker network ls` ) when executing your `docker run` command.

Once attached, your app will be able to reach the containers started by compose using their names as the host. Eg: `http://mongo:27017`

Comment: app is trying to connect in `localhost:27017` and not `http://mongo:27017`, how fix this?

Comment: Override it using env variable by passing key and value as SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/test